# Can we get a method name using java.util.function?

Tags: java, methods, java-8, functional-programming, method-reference

I tried to do:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String... args){
        final String string = "a";
        final Supplier<?> supplier = string::isEmpty;
        System.out.println(supplier);
     }
}
```

I get:

```java
HelloWorld$$Lambda$1/471910020@548c4f57
```

I would like to get the string `isEmpty`. How can I do this?

EDIT: the code of the method I created is this one:

```java
public class EnumHelper {
    private final static String values = "values";
    private final static String errorTpl = "Can't find element with value `{0}` for enum {1} using getter {2}()";

    public static <T extends Enum<T>, U> T getFromValue(T enumT, U value, String getter) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final T[] elements = (T[]) ReflectionHelper.callMethod(enumT, values);

        for (final T enm: elements) {
            if (ReflectionHelper.callMethod(enm, getter).equals(value)) {
                return enm;
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidParameterException(MessageFormat.format(errorTpl, value, enumT, getter));
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't pass as parameter T::getValue, since getValue is not static. And I can't pass someEnumElem::getValue, since the `get()` will return the value of that element. I could use inside the for loop:

```java
Supplier<U> getterSupllier = enm:getValue;
if (getterSupllier.get().equals(value)) {
    [...]
}
```

but in this way `getValue` is fixed, I can't pass it as parameter. I could use some third-party library to do an `eval()`, but I really don't want to open that Pandora vase :D

EDIT 2: `Function` does work with no parameters methods, but only in `Java` 11. Unluckily I'm stuck with `Java` 8.

Comment: @MCEmperor At the *very* least: For debugging, to not print `"Checking elements for HelloWorld$$Lambda$1/471910020@548c4f57"`, but `"Checking elements for isEmpty"`. That would be great...

Comment: @Marco13 that would mean a `toString` of some kind and an _identity_ for lambdas or methods references, the designers did not do that on purpose IIRC.

Comment: @MCEmperor: It's for `enum`s. I created a generic method that from an enum, a value and a getter name, it returns the `enum` element with that value, returned by the getter specified. The only finesse is that I want to extract the name of the getter from the getter itself, not passing a string, like "getValue". This is because if the getter change in the `enum`, the compiler informs me I have to change it also when I invoke this method.

Comment: So why don’t you make your method accept a `Function` rather than a getter name? Then, instead of trying to find out the getter name, just to search for the right method to invoke, call `apply` on the function, which will already invoke the right method.

Comment: @Marco13 would an imaginary `"Checking elements for + string::isEmpty.getMethodName()` be better than `"Checking elements for isEmpty"`?

Comment: @MarcoSulla could you add it (ideally, with the code) to the question? maybe we could come up with something...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I think the point is (also in view of the question) that at some point, you only have a `Supplier`, and there's nothing you can do with it in this regard ... except for calling `toString`. Some magic `if (s instanceof MethodRef) print(((MethodRef)s).getMethodName());` might be reasonable for some cases. But I personally like having `toString` methods that return something "readable" (or at least, something useful). Figuring out which lambda/methodRef hides behind a `$$1233@456` string is awkward...

Comment: @Eugene I don't see where *identity* comes into play here. But as it has already been sorted out: There is no automatic (or at least, no obvious) way of giving it a readable `toString`, or even *deriving* a helpful string from the object. But I agree with Andrew: Providing more code might help to find  an appropriate solution.

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 10):

`string::isEmpty` will be constructed by a method `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory` which has `implMethod` among its parameters.

```
final String methodName = implMethod.internalMemberName().getName();
```

would return a method name (here, `"isEmpty"`) if we had access to the arguments passed to this factory method, and to `implMethod` in particular. The arguments generated by up-calls from the JVM that provides very specific information for the `java.lang.invoke` API.

For example, to initialise a `DirectMethodHandle` which `string::isEmpty` represents, the JVM will call the following method.

```
/**
 * The JVM is resolving a CONSTANT_MethodHandle CP entry.  And it wants our help.
 * It will make an up-call to this method.  (Do not change the name or signature.)
 * The type argument is a Class for field requests and a MethodType for non-fields.
 * <p>
 * Recent versions of the JVM may also pass a resolved MemberName for the type.
 * In that case, the name is ignored and may be null.
 */
static MethodHandle linkMethodHandleConstant(Class<?> callerClass, int refKind,
                                             Class<?> defc, String name, Object type)
```

That `name` (exactly what you requested) will be put there by the JVM, and there is no means for us to access it. For now.

To read:

- [Explicit use of LambdaMetafactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775676/explicit-use-of-lambdametafactory)
- [What are CONSTANT_MethodHandle, CONSTANT_MethodType, and CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088414/what-are-constant-methodhandle-constant-methodtype-and-constant-invokedynamic)
- [MethodHandle - What is it all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823793/methodhandle-what-is-it-all-about)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. And  I know that in Java methods are not first class citizen. Anyway remains obscure to me why such a thing is impossible in Java. For example, in Python is just simple as `str.lower.__name__`.

Comment: @MarcoSulla I''d like to know why you've changed your mind. Is there something else you want to know? How can I improve the answer?

Answer (score 7):

In short: no.

Once a method reference is used you'll have an implementation of the functional interface that you requested (`Supplier<?>` in this case), but basically all the specifics of that object as undefined (or implementation-defined to be precise).

The spec doesn't say anything about it being a separate object, what its `toString()` has to be or what else you can do with it. It's a `Supplier<?>` and basically nothing else.

The same thing applies to lambda expressions.

So if you had used

```
final Supplier<?> supplier = () -> string.isEmpty();
```

the `Supplier` would do the same thing and you also couldn't get back to the "code" of the lambda.

Comment: Is there no another class in `java.util.function` that can be used for this scope?

Answer (score 3):

In short: No, it's not possible.

---

A workaround that I've been using is to create methods that wrap `java.util.functional` instances into "named" versions.

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Named {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "a";
        Supplier<?> supplier = string::isEmpty;
        Supplier<?> named = named("isEmpty", supplier);
        System.out.println(named);

    }

    static <T> Supplier<T> named(String name, Supplier<? extends T> delegate) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(delegate, "The delegate may not be null");
        return new Supplier<T>() {
            @Override
            public T get() {
                return delegate.get();
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return name;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Of course this does not make sense for all application cases. Most importantly, it does not allow you to "derive" things like the method name of a `Supplier` *in hindsight* when you just receive it, for example, as a method argument. The reason for that is more technical, most importantly: The supplier does not have to be a method reference.

But when you control the creation of the `Supplier`, changing `string::isEmpty` to `Named.named("isEmpty", string::isEmpty)` can be a reasonable way to go.

<sub>In fact, I did this so systematically for all the functional types that I even considered pushing this into some publicly visible (GitHub/Maven) library...</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It’s weird that you are asking about the opposite of what you actually need.

You have a method that receives a string and wants to execute a method with that name, but for some unknown reason, you ask for the opposite, to get the method name from an existing supplier.

And [already written in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887438/can-we-get-a-method-name-using-java-util-function#comment102208573_57887438) before knowing the actual code, you can solve the actual problem by replacing the `String getter` parameter with `Function<T,U> getter`.

You don’t need any Reflection tool here:

```
public class EnumHelper {
    private final static String errorTpl
            = "Can't find element with value `{0}` for enum {1} using getter {2}()";

    public static <T extends Enum<T>, U> T getFromValue(
            T enumT, U value, Function<? super T, ?> getter) {

        final T[] elements = enumT.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();

        for (final T enm: elements) {
            if(getter.apply(enm).equals(value)) {
                return enm;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            MessageFormat.format(errorTpl, value, enumT, getter));
    }
}
```

The getter `Function` can be implemented via method reference, e.g.

```
ChronoUnit f = EnumHelper.getFromValue(
    ChronoUnit.FOREVER, Duration.ofMinutes(60), ChronoUnit::getDuration);
System.out.println(f);
```

I made the signature of the function parameter more generous compared to `Function<T,U>`, to raise the flexibility regarding existing functions, e.g.

```
Function<Object,Object> func = Object::toString;
ChronoUnit f1 = EnumHelper.getFromValue(ChronoUnit.FOREVER, "Years", func);
System.out.println(f1.name());
```

If printing meaningful names in the erroneous case is really important, just add a name parameter just for reporting:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>, U> T getFromValue(
        T enumT, U value, Function<? super T, ?> getter, String getterName) {

    final T[] elements = enumT.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
    for (final T enm: elements) {
        if(getter.apply(enm).equals(value)) {
            return enm;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            MessageFormat.format(errorTpl, value, enumT, getterName));
}
```

to be called like

```
ChronoUnit f = EnumHelper.getFromValue(
    ChronoUnit.FOREVER, Duration.ofMinutes(60), ChronoUnit::getDuration, "getDuration");
```

That’s still better than using Reflection for the normal operations…

Comment: Sorry, but I already tried `Function`, and it expects a method with one parameter. I have a getter, so no parameters. So you HAVE to use `Supplier`.

Comment: Did you *try* the example? Are you aware that `getDuration()` and `toString()` *are* getters with no parameter? Do you understand what an [unbound instance method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35914775/2711488) is?

Comment: I tried with `Java` 8 and `Eclipse` says: `The type String does not define isEmpty(Object) that is applicable here`. No problem with Java `11`. But since I'm stuck with `Java` 8, I have to use `Supplier`. So yes, I tried the example, and I suggest you to read question tags better, and chamomile.

Comment: @MarcoSulla as a general advice, if you want to be successful as programmer, you should try to learn the concepts instead of posting strong opinions derived from anecdotal evidence. I gave a link that explains the *unbound instance method reference* and there’s no reason given to assume that this was a JDK 11 feature. The example, I gave, works with JDK 8 with both, Eclipse and standard `javac`. But it does not contain a method reference to `String::isEmpty` and it’s not clear, how this method requiring an **enum** type should work with a method on `String` as argument.

Comment: So why Eclipse gives me error with Java 8? I tried with bound and unbound lambdas.

Comment: I don’t know *what* you’ve tried. As said, my example works in Eclipse, but, as also said, it doesn’t contain a `String::isEmpty` reference. I also did already mention that `String::isEmpty` can’t work with your `getFromValue` method, as that method mandates an `enum` type and `String` is not an `enum` type. If you managed to make it work with JDK 11, the code must look entirely different than the setup of your question. So without knowing that setup, I can’t say why it doesn’t work with JDK 8.

Comment: I just make it working with `Java` 8 using `Function<String, Boolean>` for String:isEmpty. `Function<?, ?>` and Function<Object, Object>` does work only in  `Java` 10+. I want toaccept your answer, but I don't understand why you use `Function<? super T, ?> getter` as parameter instead of simply `Function<T, ? extends Object> getter`

Comment: Why do you think, `? extends Object` is simpler than just `?`? The reason to use `? super T` is explained in [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488), it raises the reusability regarding preexisting functions. E.g. consider an existing function, `Function<Object,String> f = Object::toString;` which is valid for the `getFromValue` method, as it can process a supertype of `T`. It’s the same reason why we use `?` (shorthand for `? extends Object`) instead of `Object` for the function’s result type.

Comment: <<`The reason to use ? super T is [...] it raises the reusability regarding preexisting functions`>> Well, but in the code there's already `T extends Enum<T>`... ### <<`Why do you think, ? extends Object is simpler than just ?`>> It's not, but it does not compile on `Java` 8.

Comment: <<`Object does not match T extends Enum<T>`>> Excuse me, but the scope is to invoke the getter of the passed enum. Why should I allow the user to pass a `Object` that clearly have no getter that will give to me the requested enum value?

Comment: Anyway your code with `?` or `Object` does not work, as this link demonstrates: https://www.onlinegdb.com/HyJ0gNMur But `?` works for the second generic argument, so it's ok to write `Function<T, ?> getter`