# How can we monitor the exact idle time between submitting a task as CompletableFuture for execution and actually running it?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to gather specific data on how long a task waits between being submitted and actually being executed. The idea is to be able to closely monitor the existing threadpool and tasks that are submitted for execution.

Let's assume I have an `ExecutorService` with a `fixedThreadPool`.

I'm also using a composition of completableFutures to perform a set of tasks asynchronously.
I'd like to be able to track within my logs the exact time a certain task had to wait in the queue before being taken for execution.
The way I see it I need two things:

1. A way to label `CompletableFuture` (or the `Supplier` functions passed to `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`)
   This I could potentially do by providing a wrapper method for the Supplier as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57888886 and overwrite the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` method so it will internally log which named supplier was provided
2. A way to monitor the time between the submission and execution of a specific Runnable to the threadpool executor.
   This I can achieve by extending the `ThreadPoolExecutor`and providing some custom logging in the `beforeExecute()` and `execute()` method

What I'm kind of 'stuck' on now is linking both of them together. The `beforeExecute()` method override gives me the thread and the runnable - but the thread in itself doesn't tell me much yet, and the runnable isn't named in any way so I can't really know which exact task is taken for execution. Of course I can add additional logs in the task implementations themselves and then assume that they will be right next to the log from `beforeExecute()`. The problem still remains for `execute()` itself, since that one is called internally after using the `CompletableFuture` composition.

So how can I properly link the information from the executor service, with some labelling of the exact tasks provided as CompletableFutures as in the example below?

```
List<Foo> results = createResults();
results.forEach(r -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(r)
  .thenCompose(result -> addSomething(result, something)
  .thenCombine(addSomethingElse(result, somethingElse), (r1, r2) -> result)
  .thenCompose(r -> doSomething(result).thenCompose(this::setSomething))
  .thenApply(v -> result))));

...

// At some point join() is called to actually wait for execution and completion
listOfFutures.join()
```

And each of the functions called within return a `CompletableFuture<Foo>` created by:

```
    private CompletableFuture<Foo> setSomething(Foo foo) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            foo.description = "Setting something";
            return foo;
        }, myExecutorService);
    }
```

So even by wrapping the `Supplier<T>` to have it labeled, how am I able to link this with the tracking within the `execute()` and `beforeExecute()` method of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` when that one operates on Runnables instead of Suppliers?